# How to stop left and right swiping after a condition in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating an app in which I'm getting problem to handle left and right swiping.

I want to stop left and right swiping after a condition.

This is my code:

```
public class MyAttendance extends Fragment{

    int pos = 0; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_attendance, container, false);

        final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                                       float velocityY) {
                    //Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "onFling has been called!");
                    final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                    final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                    final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                    try {

                        if ((Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"right to left",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            pos++;

                            if (pos == 0)

                            {
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                c.add(Calendar.DATE, pos);
                                snddate = df.format(c.getTime());

                                Hit_dataFrag_myatt();

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"right to left current",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                             else
                                 {
                                     Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                     SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                     c1.add(Calendar.DATE, pos);
                                     snddate = df1.format(c1.getTime());

                                     Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                     SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                     todate = df2.format(c2.getTime());

                                     if (c1.getTime().compareTo(c2.getTime()) < 0){
                                         Hit_dataFrag_myatt();

                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"right to left"+snddate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                     }else if (c1.getTime().compareTo(c2.getTime())==0){
                                         Hit_dataFrag_myatt();
                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"right to left"+snddate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     }
// at this codition i want to stop swiping
else if (c1.getTime().compareTo(c2.getTime()) > 0){
                                         // At this conditon i want to stop swiping...
                                          }
                                 }
                        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"left to right",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            pos--;
                            if (pos == 0)
                            {
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                c.add(Calendar.DATE, pos);
                                snddate = df.format(c.getTime());
                                Hit_dataFrag_myatt();

                                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"left to right current",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                               }
                            else
                                {
                                    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                    c1.add(Calendar.DATE, pos);
                                    snddate = df1.format(c1.getTime());


                                    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                    todate = df2.format(c2.getTime());


                                   /* Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                    c.add(Calendar.DATE, pos);
                                    snddate = df.format(c.getTime());*/


                                   if(c1.getTime().compareTo(c2.getTime())<0) {

                                       Hit_dataFrag_myatt();

                                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "left to right" + snddate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                   }
                                }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // nothing
                    }
                    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                }
            });

            v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });


        return v;
    } 
}
```

Please help me to stop swiping after a condition,I mentioned that where i want to stop swiping in my code..

Thanks

Comment: override  getSwipeDirs

Comment: if ur using a recycler view

Comment: You can try to make `gesture = new GestureDetector()..` with empty code inside condition. Therefore, it will not work.

Comment: @Nitin Patel...how to implement gesture = new Detector().. in my code please tell me..

Comment: What is condition to stop swiping in code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

First define variable

```
int pos = 0;
GestureDetector gesture;
```

Then remove `final GestureDetector` words ahead from gesture.

Then try below code to stop swiping adding in condition:

```
    else if (c1.getTime().compareTo(c2.getTime()) > 0){
    // At this conditon i want to stop swiping...

    gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),null);
}
```

Comment: after what condition?

Comment: i mentioned in the code else if (c1.getTime().compareTo(c2.getTime()) > 0){     // At this conditon i want to stop swiping   }

Comment: Have you debug and check that it goes in condition?

Comment: In this when position ==0 at this conditon  i want to stop left to right swiping